# how to create a table for all drawings in a map in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to report all the edits in a map? Like if we create a new point or new line or new polygon , Is it possible to create table for that so that we can communicate the changes to database.
I saw draw feature example in which we can scratch a map by pressing shift button . But is it possible to delete some features from the map like that example (free hand mode)? 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you only add or delete features on vector layers then the events 'featureadded' and 'featureremoved' can help you to collect the changes.